# Parsing returned value from stored procedure into table/variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure, which uses couple of functions, and those functions are comparing some data.
For example:

function one:

```
if @x is not null
    begin
       if @x >  @y
          return 'y cannot be less than x'
```

and on stored procedure I declare some variables which are our Xs and Ys.

Then I starting new transaction, for example:

```
begin tran test;
    exec [dbo].[My_stored_procedure]  # stored prodecure which using function I wrote above.    

               'some_value','some_value' # our X and Y
               rollback test;
```

and everything works correctly, when condition from function (x > y) is met, then we can see returned message "'y cannot be less than x'". And I want that message, to be saved in variable or table, but without editing stored procedure/function. I tried something like that:

```
begin tran test;
        CREATE TABLE stored_test
        (
       result nvarchar(2000)
    )
           INSERT INTO stored_test(result)  exec [dbo].[My_stored_procedure] 

            'some_value','some_value' 
             rollback test;
```

And it works, but "result" is emtpy. And I want it to contain return message from function, which are used in stored procedure.

Comment: what do you mean 'returning message'? to make `insert into ... exec` work you have to return recordset from the procedure, by making `select <your function>()` inside the procedure, for example.

Comment: Rollback cancels all actions, and where is your function

Comment: Yeah it cancels all actions, but before that I should seen result of SELECT, I just did not include it on code below, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the stored procedure to get any return value from it. You need to declare an output variable in the stored procedure and then store that message in the variable, and at the last call procedure like:

```
 EXECUTE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD @SalesYTD = @SalesYTDBySalesPerson OUTPUT
```